# Why can I leave out an import statement when chaining methods, but not if I call them individually?

Tags: java, swing, import, awt

For example, in this simple Java program:

1. If I write:

`frame.getContentPane().add(button);`

I only need to `import javax.swing.*;` and the code compiles perfectly.

2. However, if I write:

`Container cont = frame.getContentPane();
cont.add(button);`

I have to both `import javax.swing.*;` and `import java.awt.*;` for there not to be a `cannot find symbol` compiler error.

Aren't both ways of writing it technically exactly the same? Why need less or more import statements one way or the other?

When I'm calling it in the first way as seen in my example, doesn't getContentPane() still return a Container type object even though I might not be referring to it with a Container reference variable?

Comment: `Container` is class from the `java.awt` package, presumably `JFrame` is class from `javax.swing` package, they live in different locations. *"Aren't both ways of writing it technically exactly the same?"* - Nope, they are different APIs/packages/name spaces

Comment: Thanks, however it still doesn't clear it up for me. When I'm calling it in the first way as seen in my example, doesn't `getContentPane()` still return a `Container` type object even though I might not be referring to it with a `Container` reference variable?

Comment: Ah sorry, that has more to do with the fact the via `JFrame`, the `Container` has been imported so Java can find it, but if you declare variable Java wants to know which `Container` you mean so it make sure the assignment is correct/valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Java Language Specification:

> An import declaration allows a named type or a static member to be referred to
>   by a simple name (§6.2) that consists of a single identifier.
>
> Without the use of an appropriate import declaration, the only way to refer to a
>   type declared in another package, or a static member of another type, is to use
>   a fully qualified name (§6.7).

So the only reason you require the `import` is so you can use the "shortened" classname. The following should work without using `import java.awt.*`:

```
java.awt.Container cont = frame.getContentPane();
cont.add(button);
```

The "chaining"-version of your code implicitly uses the qualified classname, so there is no need for an `import`-statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Definitely helps me to make sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a variable of type `java.awt.Container`

Comment: Thanks, however it still doesn't clear it up for me. When I'm calling it in the first way as seen in my example, doesn't `getContentPane()` still return a `Container` type object even though I might not be referring to it with a `Container` reference variable?

Comment: The Import is only necessary to be able to write `Container` instead of `java.awt.Container`. If you use the FQCN, no import is necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because java's `import` is a little different from other languages.

In Java, during runtime **all the classes in the classpath are present** to the JVM.

The import statements are actually provided to help the compiler to identify which `Class` you are referring to in-case there are many classes with the same name.

> So, why are they not required when method chaining?

Because the compiler can easily know which type is returned by the particular method, so there can never be an ambiguity.

Comment: This clears it up! I've only learned C and am learning Java now, good to know about the import statement and how it differs from <include>. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Container` class is in this `package:java.awt.*,` then your IDE complains asking you to import those files as well.

Comment: Thanks, however it still doesn't clear it up for me. When I'm calling it in the first way as seen in my example, doesn't `getContentPane()` still return a `Container` type object even though I might not be referring to it with a `Container` reference variable?

Answer (score 0):

When we write:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(button);
```

getContentPane() returns an anonymous container object at run time, by which the add(button) method is called. If you happen to check JFrame class it will look something like this:

```
import java.awt.Container;
public class JFrame extends SomeClassName {  
    public Container getContentPane() {
        Container cont;
        //Some great code which assigns container with its appropriate value.
        return cont;
    }
}
```

While when we write:

```
Container cont = frame.getContentPane();  
cont.add(button);
```

We are creating a known object i.e naming it ourselves for which the compiler must know in which package the class Container belongs.